# Codeigniter Use HOOK

Tags: php, codeigniter, hook, token

how to use hook in codeigniter?

i have config/hooks.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

$hook['post_controller_constructor'] = array(
        'class'    => 'init',
        'function' => 'start',
        'filename' => 'init.php',
        'filepath' => 'hooks',
        'params'   => array('index')
);
```

and then init.php

```
class init {

    function start() {
        if(strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == 'options') die();
        $ci =& get_instance();
        $session = $ci->load->library('session');
        $tokenAuth = $ci->load->library('tokenAuth');
    }
}
```

how to check the session or tokenAuth. if exist???
thanks.

Comment: first ti enable the hook , than you use hook type "post", so please submit the form and after check it.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37970201/restrict-user-from-unauthorized-access/37970760#37970760